# A clicking every couple of pedal turns (video included)

Tags: chain, gears, repair

I have been using a hybrid trek for a couple of weeks.

The bike is still very new with only around 150 miles done.

This morning on a ride it kept clicking every few pedal turns.

I cut the ride short as I didn't want to damage it further.

Any ideas from the video?

Comment: It's a brand new bike and it's defective: take it back to the shop and get them to fix it for you. They should do this for free. If you try to fix it yourself and mess it up, you run the risk that they'll say the whole thing was your fault. Hopefully, the answers will explain what the problem is, but you should treat that as "for educational purposes only". :)

Comment: Thanks @DavidRicherby

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like a stiff link in the chain. In the video there is a noticeable jolt in the chain through the derailleur every time there is a noise.

The chain makes a full revolution only every few pedal turns, hence it’s a few pedal turns between each jump.

Have a read here: https://www.bikeride.com/stiff-chain-link/

You could diagnose and fix it yourself, if you have a chain tool, but if it is a new bike, it’s something the shop should help you with in the first instance.

Comment: thanks for the heads up, do you think it is still ok to ride to the bike shop, which is around 6 miles away or could I cause further damage?

Comment: also is there anything I can do to prevent this in the future or is it just bad luck?

Comment: Try wiggling each link of the chain sideways and up-down. It may become unstuck.

Comment: @user30609 *do you think it is still ok to ride to the bike shop*  I wouldn't without throughly examining the chain.  You can already see the derailleur jump forward when the likely-bad link goes through.  If that bad link is from a pin or side plate coming loose it might catch on the derailleur badly enough to rip it right off, which would likely trash the entire rear wheel and leave you stranded.

Comment: @Swifty it was a stiff chain and it has been fixed. Thanks very much for your help!